# FabricUI DatePicker/Calendar days highlighting and navigation callback

Tags: typescript, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I'm using DatePicker/Calendar in current project. Looks great but having some issues I can't addredd myself currently.

Is there a possibility to get notified by component or somehow inject callback to "month changed"? 
Tried to track this change event and saw Calendar has private function `_onNavigateDayDate` and `_navigateMonthPickerDay` but no way to go from there that I'm aware of.

Additionally I saw option to disable some dates passing an array to `restrictedDates`, that is fine, but if I only need to mark those days in different style? Any option to add specific style to a day? Some custom rendering for days or other way around?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue in the meantime? I'm trying to solve something very similar.